# Units in the coordinate ring on a reductive group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, schemes

Let $K$ be a field and $G$ a connected reductive group over  $K$.
Can we describe  $K[G]^{*}$?

Comment: Up to multiplying by a scalar, any invertible function is a character, see http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/unitthm.pdf